# What is max limit of an Array/NSMutableArray? I am not getting full JSON data in log

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray

Here is JSON file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WOE6HEylc5FnAo9NekMdwPU3xEuGUgMg/view?usp=sharing

I am getting this JSON data, I am trying to print JSON but it is not printing full JSON.

Inside JSON, there is one key "file", it contains base64 encoded data. Its value is very large.

I am trying to print the whole JSON or only value for a key "file" but I am getting incomplete data.

I do not know, why I am getting half data.

Here is the code I wrote,

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray=[json copy];
NSDictionary *threadDict=[mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSLog(@"Ticket Thread Dict is : %@",threadDict);// It is not printing full json

NSMutableArray *attachmentArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
attachmentArray  =[threadDict objectForKey:@"attach"];
NSDictionary *attachDictionary=[attachmentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *fileData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attachDictionary objectForKey:@"file"]];
NSLog(@"Fina Name is : %@",fileData); // this is not printing full data
```

Comment: Ask yourself which of the two is limited: `NSString` or `NSLog`. If the first is OK then it can be printed using multiple logs...

Comment: how to get full data? What is the solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its nothing to do with the size of your `Array/NSMutableArray`. Earlier i have faced the same issue, `NSLog` is not able to log my base64 string completely so later i used

```
printf("base64 String %s", [jsonString UTF8String]);
```

Try to use the above code in place of `NSLog`. It will work and you can see your log.

Comment: ok, Madhu. Let me check it.

Comment: Since its a base64 string it may take lot of time to print. As per my knowledge it will work. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: yes, Now I am getting a full string.

Comment: Ok. Accept the answer so that it will be useful to others.

Comment: yes sure. One more small help I need.

Comment: my project is crashing is it showing error that *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'***

Comment: It happens when the JSON contains single attachment data i.e "attach" is not empty and next "attach" is empty.

Comment: That's a common problem when you are trying to access the elements that are greater than the size of the array. Its nothing to do with the log try to check your array properly. If you still need help there are lot of similar questions related to your issue, so check them once.